# CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch

Tags: html, css, mime-types, mime-message

My Site style sheet is being ignored by every browser I have tested it one. I'm getting this error when testing on IE9 - SEC7113: CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch

Here is the html from the header referencing it. Let me know if you need more to go by.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <!--The style sheet below is the one being ignored-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" charset="UTF-8" href="Styles/Site.css"  />

    <!-- Skin CSS file -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/assets/skins/sam/skin.css" />
    <!-- Utility Dependencies -->
    <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/element/element-min.js"></script> 
    <!-- Needed for Menus, Buttons and Overlays used in the Toolbar -->
    <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/container/container_core-min.js">     </script>
    <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/menu/menu-min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/button/button-min.js"></script>
    <!-- Source file for Rich Text Editor-->
    <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/editor/editor-min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/editor/simpleeditor-min.js"></script>


</head>
```

Comment: Is this on your own personal server? It might not be sending the CSS file with the correct mime type.

Comment: What's your server ? Can you change [the .htaccess files](http://wiki.joyent.com/display/gen/Configuring+MIME+Types+in+.htaccess) ?

Comment: try to put absolute path instead relative

Comment: Why do you need the `charset="UTF-8"` there? It's not actually going to affect the MIME type of the stylesheet when it gets requested.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out, the company I just started working for failed to install the Static Content features for the IIS when setting up my computer. So it was ignoring all my style sheets, images, and links.

Answer (score 0):

Your server apparently sends wrong media type information. This cannot be verifies from outside your server, though.

Answer (score 0):

I had a typo in my file name and  and spelled it myFile.ccs vs myFile.css, both in link and in file.  Firefox was fine, but IE returned this error.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that with my new Windows 10 machine, I'd failed to enable Static Content in my local IIS.  To do so, go to "Turn Windows Features On or Off" from your Control Panel, and navigate to the following location:

[image]

Make sure this "Static Content" option is checked.  Then, bring up a command window as an administrator and perform an iisreset.

Boom, fixed.